# Visual Studio Unit Test locking dll

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, pinvoke

Simple unit test for abstract class with p/invoked methods is leaving the unmanaged dll locked when tests are executed. Oddly enough the lock does not happen when debugging the test, only when test is run.

Similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696825/prevent-vstest-discovery-engine-locking-dlls) reported on Visual Studio 2012 and I am using a similar workaround, a bit less hacky but nonetheless not a good solution.

### Workaround

Added a "teardown" method to be executed once tests terminate to manually free the unmanaged library.

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

[AssemblyCleanup]
public static void Teardown()
{
    foreach (ProcessModule mod in Process.GetCurrentProcess().Modules)
    {
        if (mod.ModuleName == "example.dll")
        {
            FreeLibrary(mod.BaseAddress);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the DLL being loaded by the test framework, you, or is it linker bound?  If linker bound, you have the option to leverage delayed DLL loading to see if that provides any insight. Google: PfnDliHook __pfnDliNotifyHook2

Comment: It is being loaded by the framework, unfortunately I don't have access to this hook function.

Comment: I don't know if VSTest has any option to enable/disable Shadow Copy.  Sometimes changing that setting in NUnit has helped with odd assembly/DLL problems.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for running unit tests in vs:

- Run an instance of the console as administrator and enter this script:

  taskkill /F /IM vstest* /T
- before running a test switch to the console and execute the line above to kill any process related to the test framework.

I also manually build the test project before running a test because if I forget to kill the processes, vs will be stuck in build mode forever.

Unfortunately all this does not solve my main issue which is that I need to kill vs every 20 minutes while testing or debugging because it gets slow to the point of being unusable. ):

For fairness I must add that I run the tests from a Resharper test session.